# I made a main menu but don't know how to make the game start

Tags: python, pygame

So, I made a main menu. Now I have to make the "main game". But how should I do it? I mean I have to code the game but how do I start the game when I'm finished by pressing the Start button. What do I have to code into the start button (in my case `greenButton`) so it will open the game? Do I have to make a new File and if so, how do I make the new File open after pressing the Start button. I'll put my code here just if it is really necessaly:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
win.fill((0, 180, 210))

class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

def redrawWindow():
    win.fill((0, 180, 210))
    greenButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    redButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))

run = True
greenButton = button((0, 255, 0), 280, 255, 250, 100, "Start")
redButton = button ((255, 0, 0), 280, 380, 250, 100, "Quit")
while run:
    redrawWindow()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the button")
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the 2button")
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                greenButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                greenButton.color = (0, 255, 0)
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                redButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                redButton.color = (255, 0, 0)







    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a game state and draw the scene dependent on the state.

For instance add a variable `game_state` with the value `"menu"`.

```py
game_state = "menu"
```

If the button is pressed the change state of the game:

```py
if greenButton.isOver(pos):
    print("clicked the button")
    game_state = "game"
```

Draw different scenes, dependent on the state of the game gamestate

```py
if game_state == "menu":
    redrawMenuWindow()
elif game_state == "game":
    redrawGameWindow()
```

The events have to be handled different, dependent on the state of the game.

Complete example code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()


win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
win.fill((0, 180, 210))

class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False


def redrawMenuWindow():
    win.fill((0, 180, 210))
    greenButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    redButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # [...]

greenButton = button((0, 255, 0), 280, 190, 250, 100, "Start")
redButton = button((255, 0, 0), 280, 310, 250, 100, "Quit")

game_state = "menu"
run = True
while run:
    if game_state == "menu":
        redrawMenuWindow()
    elif game_state == "game":
        redrawGameWindow()
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if game_state == "menu":
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                    print("clicked the button")
                    game_state = "game"
                if redButton.isOver(pos):
                    print("clicked the 2button")
                    run = False
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                    greenButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
                else:
                    greenButton.color = (0, 255, 0)
                if redButton.isOver(pos):
                    redButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
                else:
                    redButton.color = (255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: @RMR_MD I've add the complete example code. Note, the window turns black when "Start" is clicked, because of the code in `redrawGameWindow()`

Answer (score 0):

The way that you code is now, you can put the main part of your game in a function, say... 'main_game_function' and the where you you have `print ("clicked the button")` just replace it with `main_game_function ()`.